# Special transformation!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, intuition, transformation

Can someone explain why this special transformation work?

suppose we have a differential equation in standard form.

$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$

If the differential equation is in this special form

$$(a_1x+b_1y+c_1)dx+(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)dy=0$$

then,

Let (h,k) be the solution to the differential equation such that

$$a_1h+b_1k+c_1=0$$
$$a_2h+b_2k+c_2=0$$

The transformation is then

$$x=X+h$$

$$y=Y+k$$

I can't understand why this works! Can someone provide both an intuitive explanation and proof if there is. I just explore the world of differential equation.

It is obvious that the above differential equation is not in homogeneous form, Bernoulli's, separable variable or exact form!

Comment: Did you mean for one of these to be $y=Y+h$, for example?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my foolish mistake.

Comment: Do you know how to explain the above transformation?

Comment: It still seems like there is a typo, like it should be $x = X + h, y = Y + k$.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @Crazy: Now we have $x = X + h, y = Y + k, dx = dX, dy = dY$. Substitute that into the special form you wrote, and then using the "such that" reduce it. Solve for $\dfrac{dY}{dX}$ and what do you get?

Comment: In the book it is written under special transformation.

Comment: A homogeneous equation such that it can be expressed in the form of $f(X,Y)=g(\frac{Y}{X})$

Comment: @Crazy: That is correct, you get $$\dfrac{dY}{dX} = \dfrac{f_1(x,y)}{f_2(x,y)}$$, which can be written as your previous comment states.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me with this as well for today
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317390/differential-equation-of-standard-form-proof-verification
I am about five days fresh with differential equation

Answer (score 0):

the basic idea is you get rid of the terms $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ by solving for $a_{1}h+b_{1}k+c_{1} = 0$ and $a_{2}h+b_{2}k+c_{2}=0$, and now that you don't have any constants the equation turns into a simple homogeneous diff equation.. just remember to subsitue back $X = x - h$ and $Y = y-k$