# Differential equation of standard form proof verification!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

The question is,

Show that if $μ(x,y)$ & $v(x,y) $ are integrating factors of

$$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$

such that $μ(x,y)/v(x,y)$ is not constant! then

$$μ(x,y)=c(v(x,y))$$

is a solution to the above differential equation! for every constant c.

My try

$μ(x,y)M(x,y)+μ(x,y)N(x,y)=0$

If it is a solution to differential equation then

$\frac{\partial μ(x,y)}{\partial y}{M(x,y)}+μ(x,y)\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y}$=$\frac{\partial μ(x,y)}{\partial x}{N(x,y)}+μ(x,y)\frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}$

$v(x,y)M(x,y)+v(x,y)N(x,y)=0$

For this to be a solution, as for $v(x,y)$

$\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y}{M(x,y)}+v(x,y)\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y}$=$\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x}{N(x,y)}+v(x,y)\frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}$

We can say that

$$v(x,y)M(x,y)+v(x,y)N(x,y)=μ(x,y)M(x,y)+μ(x,y)N(x,y)$$

So by ratio we have

$\frac{μ(x,y)}{v(x,y)}=c$